# Delete a digit then sum

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, number-theory

Take a number $(x)$, then create the complete list of the numbers formed by deleting single digits from its base **ten** representation $(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)$.
If the sum of those new numbers equals $x$ we call the number a special number.

**Example :**

1729404 = 729404 (delete 1) + 129404 (delete 7) + 179404 + 172404 + 172904 + 172944 + 172940

13758846 = 3758846 + 1758846 + 1358846 + 1378846 + 1375846 + 1375846 + 1375886 + 1375884

(in the 2<sup>nd</sup> example we see 1375846 twice.)

**Question :**

- Is the list of these kind of numbers infinite?
- If not, find the largest number (without the aid of a computer) with this property, then prove it!

Comment: Did you mean infinite on your first question? Or perhaps start the second question by "if so,"?

Comment: @stackreader 
: thanks for correction

Comment: Are we allowed to use any base?

Comment: @JonathanAllan : Use base 10

Comment: [Related OEIS sequence (spoiler alert)](https://oeis.org/A131639)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If one considers numbers that are less than / greater than rather than equal to it becomes clear that the list must be finite. The sums of the list of numbers of length $12$ or more must be greater than the requirement even if all trailing digits are zeros ($11$ times a **tenth** of a number is greater than the original number, and the multiple only increases as we add more digits).
>
>  If the largest number does have $11$ digits the last **ten** digits must all be **zero** (to make a single $000000000=0$ in the sum).
>  Working backwards with $x$ as this digit:
>  $x\times 10,000,000,000 = 10\times x \times 1,000,000,000 + 0$
>  implies $x$ can be any digit, hence the largest possible is when $x=9$, which is:
>  $90,000,000,000$

Comment: Cripes, I wrote a solution only to see it was pretty much the same as yours.

Answer (score 5):

simple proof that such numbers are finite.

> 11 = 1 + 1 = 2
> 111 = 11 + 11 + 11 = 33
> 1111 = 111 + 111 + 111 + 111 = 444
> 11111 = 5555
> 111111 = 66666
> 1111111 = 777777
> 11111111 = 8888888
> 111111111 = 99999999
> 1111111111 = 1111111110 (possible around this range of numbers)
> 11111111111 = 12222222221 (from here an higher will always have too big results).
> The result is highly dependent on the number of digits. The number of digits that allow a correct answer is very limited and vary slightly depending on the first digit.

Comment: I like the inductive layout :)

Comment: Just a note - you missed the all trailing zeros trick allowing 8 solutions higher than your upper bound.